# DataTables - JS function cannot see the table variable

Tags: javascript, variables, datatable, scope, referenceerror

Hope somebody can help me to understand this issue and resolve it. I have a table define as DataTable in the Document ready section

```
$(document).ready(function (){


             let table = $('.invoice-data').DataTable();

            //update
            $('.invoice-data .net-price').on('change',function(){
                let row_id = $(this).attr('row_id');
                calculate_line_totals(row_id);
                calculate_invoice_totals();
            });
});
```

and then inside the calculate_invoice_totals() function I'm trying to call the table variable to get the column total.

```
 function calculate_invoice_totals(){

            let vat_tot = 0;
            let net_tot = 0;
            let grs_tot = 0;

            net_tot = table.column(4).data().reduce(function(a,b){return a+b});
            vat_tot = table.column(6).data().reduce(function(a,b){return a+b});
            grs_tot = parseFloat(net_tot)+parseFloat(vat_tot);

            $('#inv_netval').val(net_tot.toFixed(2));
            $('#inv_vatval').val(vat_tot.toFixed(2));
            $('#inv_grosval').val(grs_tot.toFixed(2));
        }
```

when I run this code, I get table is not define message.

[image: Error on the console log]

I believe this is due to scope of the variable. But Datatable does not work if I define outside the document.ready function. Could somebody please help me to fix this problem and get the column total.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it moving the code inside the document ready function